# Robust representation of PathBuf for code generation in Rust

Tags: serialization, rust, code-generation

I have a list of pairs of `PathBuf`s and I want to generate code that will give an efficient mapping function - looking up a path and giving me the corresponding path in the pair. To do this I am creating a static hash-map with [`phf`](https://docs.rs/phf/0.7.21/phf/).

My current implementation is a `pub static PATH: phf::Map<&'static str, &'static str>`. I have an access function `fn lookup(path: PathBuf) -> Option<PathBuf>` that unwraps the `PathBuf` into a `str`, does the lookup and wraps up the resulting `str` into a new `PathBuf`. I generate the string representations of the paths in the code using `to_string_lossy` which works fine at the moment but clearly is not robust.

I think it might be sensible to give up representing the paths in the generated code as strings at all and instead serialize to `[u8]` with e.g. `bincode` to be sure that the representation is robust.

Is a sensible approach? Is there a safe way that keeps the "natural" string representation?

**Despite my going back and forth below, I'm still on the fence and the question remains: Should I bincode serialize my objects and put the binary into `phf::Hash` or store the objects directly.** The former feels like unnecessary overhead (but with bincode perhaps very little). The latter feels fragile - I have to implement a wrapper type around `PathBuf` to get hashing and to implement `Debug` that gives a  correct representation in code - and exactly how to ensure that I am not sure.

[@Jmb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518863/robust-representation-of-pathbuf-for-code-generation-in-rust#comment84032700_48518863):

> Can't you use `OsStr`? After all it is the underlying representation used by `PathBuf`

Got me to realise I was making things harder for myself. I was testing things out by editing the code directly instead of changing the code generator. Therefore I was using the `phf` macro instead of the code generator. Using the code generator, I get a nice clear error message.

I could use `PathBuf` directly but need to write a `PhfHash` `impl` for it. To avoid a orphan implementation, I'd need to put a type-wrapper around it.

However, `OsStr` doesn't make any guarantees about its representation. `as_bytes` is only available on Unix. `OsStr` and `PathBuf` do implement `Hash` however.

The `phf` docs say about `PhfHasher`:

> This differs from the standard library's `Hash` trait in that `PhfHash`'s results must be architecture independent so that hashes will be consistent between the host and target when cross compiling.

...since I am generating code that relies on (relative) paths remaining valid between compilation and running, I think this isn't an issue and I can simply implement `PhfHash` by forwarding to `Hash`.

For all my worrying about how to serialise `PathBuf` in a robust way, phf actually just relies on formatting with `Debug` to turn the the keys into generated code.

I guess perhaps it is time I stopped worrying and embraced `Debug` for code generation. However the `Debug` implementation for OsStr does not produce a valid code representation of an `OsStr` but instead just prints a string (Debug is implemented manually, not derived). My OsStr wrapper would also have to implement `Debug` to produce a valid code representation of the struct.

Comment: Can't you use `OsStr`? After all it is the underlying representation used by `PathBuf`

Comment: @Jmb I assume the sticking point with `OsStr` (or `PathBuf`, for that matter) is that it doesn't implement [`PhfHash`](https://docs.rs/phf/0.7.21/phf/trait.PhfHash.html), which OP is trying to use.

Comment: @trentcl - yes but it was Jmb's reply that made me realise that (see edit to question)

Comment: So... what are you even asking anymore?

Comment: @Shepmaster - I'm sorry I have been uncleay. I will implement this with binary serialization. My question remains: Is there a robust, sane, way to do this without going via serialization to a binary array.